# Why sometimes ImageTarget isn't recognize?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using Vuforia with Unity and I try to track an ImageTarget( that with stones from Vuforia site). The problem is that sometimes (in 20-30% of  cases) it takes like 10-20 seconds to recognize the ImageTarget even if I put it very clearly in front of the camera. Other problem is when the ImageTarget disappears from the scene and reappears sometimes works perfectly sometimes not. Any suggestion why this is happening? (I'm new in Vuforia)

Answer (score 1):

If its default project without your scripts - then may be quality of your camera is not enough to track correctly image targets all the time. Also vuforia sometimes has bug with loading resources with image targets but if you do not reload app and image been tracked it is only quality of your camera.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have another question, I add this code in the DefaultTrackableEventHandler script from an ImageTarget:                  protected virtual void Update()
    {
        calculateLength();

    }
    protected virtual void  calculateLength()
    {
        Vector3 delta = Camera.main.transform.position - mTrackableBehaviour.transform.position;
        float d = delta.magnitude/28 ;
        Debug.Log("The distance is : " + d +"cm");
    }. Can this affect the ImageTarget detection?

Comment: Nope, this can't do anything to detection. But still better to use fixed update

Comment: Can you mark question answered, if you have no other questions? :)

Comment: I'm waiting for other suggestions  because I tried on different devices with good camera quality (Huawei P10 and Huawei P20 lite) and get the same behavior.